# How to create interest in prayers?

Tags: soul

My problem is that i really wish to say prayers by heart. When its a favorite food to eat,
then i get up quickly from my place but when it comes to prayers, I delay them as long
as I can or don't perform them. I have read about the punishment that will be given to us
and I am very hopeless from my attitude that even that does not encourage me.I wish to love
Allah. I feel my heart is sick and black. Is there any way out of this gumrahi?? I wish when I hear Azaan i forget about everything and say prayers. I wish to feel the prayers and
concentrate.Here are symptoms of weak faith I read and I wan't to ask that is there any
solution for a hopeless human like me?? 
1.Performing Acts of Worship Poorly.
2.His breast gets tightened, his mood changes, he feels as if he is carrying a heavy load, and he becomes annoyed quickly because of minor things.
3.Verses of the Qur'an Have No Effect Upon Him
4.He Falls into Doubtful Matters
5.Disputing and Arguing Unnecessarily.

Comment: This post is rather disjointed; I would strongly recommend you take the time to focus your question, especially in regard to your grammar, as well as peruse the advice in our help centre on "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)".  As written, it appears to be a general call for advice rather than a practical and answerable question (see also the help centre page "[What types of questions should I avoid asking here?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asalam u Alaikum

Never loose hope in Allah, you are not hopeless. To compare myself with you, I was and quiet a bit still am far worse in this case, so you still have hope, cheer up.

You can make Salah as much fun as possible, it is not a torcher, like I race myself with myself or with my brother or my parents to offer Salah as soon as possible!. Read the below hadith and the abstract in bold I use that and it works pretty excellent.

I would advise you to take into consideration the blessings that Allah has given to you and thank Allah for giving those blessings to you, and you cant be more open regarding your feelings to others than to Allah. Plus one more thing **...think while offering Salah (Prayers) that you are watching Allah even though you can't, but Allah can see you**; It was said by Prophet Muhummad Sallallahu Aalayhi Wasalam and is a hadith mentioned in Sahih Bukahri and Sahih Muslim and Imam Nawawi's 40 Hadith

Narrated by Abu Hurairah radi'allahu'ta'ala anhu:

> One day while the Prophet was sitting in the company of some people,
>   (The angel) Gabriel came and asked, "What is faith?" Allah's Apostle
>   replied, 'Faith is to believe in Allah, His angels, (the) meeting with
>   Him, His Apostles, and to believe in Resurrection." Then he further
>   asked, "What is Islam?" Allah's Apostle replied, "To worship Allah
>   Alone and none else, to offer prayers perfectly to pay the compulsory
>   charity (Zakat) and to observe fasts during the month of Ramadan."
>   Then he further asked, **"What is Ihsan (perfection)?" Allah's Apostle
>   replied, "To worship Allah as if you see Him, and if you cannot
>   achieve this state of devotion then you must consider that He is
>   looking at you."** Then he further asked, "When will the Hour be
>   established?" Allah's Apostle replied, "The answerer has no better
>   knowledge than the questioner. But I will inform you about its
>   portents. When a slave (lady) gives birth to her master. When the
>   shepherds of black camels start boasting and competing with others in
>   the construction of tall buildings. And the Hour is one of five things
>   which nobody knows except Allah. The Prophet then recited: "Verily,
>   with Allah (Alone) is the knowledge of the Hour--." (31. 34) Then that
>   angel (Gabriel) left and the Prophet asked his companions to call him
>   back, but they could not see him. Then the Prophet said, "That was
>   Gabriel who came to teach the people their religion." Abu 'Abdullah
>   said: He (the Prophet) considered all that as a part of faith. Sahih
>   al-Bukhari, 1:2:48

Hope that helps Sister, I'll pray for you regarding this matter!